# JLabel Not Showing When resetting JFrame to setVisible(true)

Tags: jframe, jlabel

I have created an Abstract Class for common things to be useful in my entire program

```
public interface Global {

static final String regexdate="^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[13578]|1[02])|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)[- /.](0[469]|11)|(0[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])[- /.]02)[- /.]\\d{4}|29[- /.]02[- /.](\\d{2}(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|([02468][048]|[1359][26])00))$";
static final String regexemail="\\b[\\w\\.-]+@[\\w\\.-]+\\.\\w{2,4}+\\b$";
static final String regexalpha="\\b[a-zA-Z .]+\\b$";
static final String regexnumbersonly="\\b[^a-zA-Z ,.+-]*\\d\\b$";
static final String regexalphaonly="\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b$";
//address would allow any character case insensitive and numbers (for house number) "-"  space "," and "/"
static final String regexaddress="\\b[a-zA-Z\\s 0-9-,/\\n]*\\b$";
static final String regexalphanumeric="\\b[a-zA-Z0-9 .]+\\b$";
static final String regexisbn="\\b[0-9-]+\\b$";
static final String regexdecimals="\\b[^a-zA-Z ,+-]*\\d\\b$";
// single character datatype validation regex
static final String regexchar="^[.a-zA-Z\s]+$";

static LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
static DayOfWeek dayofweek=localDate.getDayOfWeek();
static int dayofmonth=localDate.getDayOfMonth();
static Month  monthofyear=localDate.getMonth();
static int year=localDate.getYear();
static String properday=dayofweek.toString().substring(0,1)+dayofweek.toString().substring(1,3).toLowerCase();
static String propermonth=monthofyear.toString().substring(0, 1)+monthofyear.toString().substring(1, 3).toLowerCase();
static String dayfull=properday+" "+Integer.valueOf(dayofmonth)+"-"+propermonth+"-"+Integer.valueOf(year).toString().substring(2,4);

static final Font myfont=new Font("Serg UI",Font.PLAIN,16);
static final Font myfontheader=new Font("Serg UI",Font.BOLD,20);
static final Font myfonttoget=new Font("serg UI",Font.CENTER_BASELINE,16);
static final Color mybackground= new Color(231, 231, 231);
public JLabel title=new JLabel("Library Management System",SwingConstants.LEFT);
public JLabel welcome=new JLabel ("Welcome :-",SwingConstants.LEFT);
public JLabel ctandd=new JLabel(dayfull);
```

}

Now I have two separate classes where i am using all of above as required

```
    admintitle.setBounds(0,0,900,49);
    title.setBounds(310, 10, 335,20);
    welcome.setBounds(1, 0, 130, 20);
    ctandd.setBounds(790, 5,225, 20);
    totalmem.setBounds(1, 25,100, 20);
    
    
    adminpanel.setBackground(new Color(1,3,45));
    
    JLabel addvalue=new JLabel("10");
    addvalue.setFont(myfont);
    addvalue.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    addvalue.setSize(20, 20);
    today.add(addvalue);

    lmember.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    separator.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    addmem.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    modifymem.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    delmem.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    admintitle.add(title);
    admintitle.add(welcome);
    admintitle.add(ctandd);
    admintitle.add(totalmem);
    
    adminpanel.add(lmember);
    adminpanel.add(separator);
    adminpanel.add(addmem);
    adminpanel.add(modifymem);
    adminpanel.add(delmem);
    adminpanel.add(separator1);
    adminpanel.add(lbook);
    adminpanel.add(separator2);
    adminpanel.add(addbook);
    adminpanel.add(modifyinven);
    adminpanel.add(delbook);
    adminpanel.add(separator3);
    adminpanel.add(lrepo);
    adminpanel.add(penaltyrepo);
    adminpanel.add(separator4);
    adminpanel.add(newrequest);
    adminpanel.add(exit);
    
    
    

    admindisplay.add(totaldue);
    admindisplay.add(totalpenalty);
    admindisplay.add(penaltyamt);
    admindisplay.add(memadded);
    admindisplay.add(booksadded);
    admindisplay.add(bookslost);
    admindisplay.add(booksoverdue);
    admindisplay.add(memdiscontinued);
    admindisplay.add(newbookrequest);
    admindisplay.add(memhead);
    admindisplay.add(separator5);
    admindisplay.add(bookhead);
    admindisplay.add(separator6);
    admindisplay.add(summary);
    admindisplay.add(today);
    admindisplay.add(weekly);
    admindisplay.add(monthly);
    admindisplay.add(yearly);

    admin.add(admintitle);
    admin.add(adminpanel);
    admin.add(admindisplay);
    admin.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println(admin.getComponentCount());
    System.out.println(admin.getComponentZOrder(title));
    System.out.println(admindisplay.getComponentCount());
    System.out.println(adminpanel.getComponentCount());
    System.out.println(admintitle.getComponentCount());
    
    
} // end of admin ui
```

from this class when I click on a button I navigate to another class

```
    addmem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do login code
        
        admin.setVisible(false);
        uiaddmem.caddmemUI(admin);
    }});
```

In another class I do something and upon user clicking back button I come back to this JFrame

```
            back.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
          modmember.setVisible(false);
          admin.setVisible(true);
          admin.toFront();
          admin.validate();
            System.out.println(admin.getComponentCount());
            System.out.println(admin.getComponentZOrder(title));
            System.out.println(admintitle.getComponentCount());
            
        }});
```

Eveything works fine except that my title, welcome, total and ctandd just disappear from the first JFrame when I make admin.setVisible(true) as above.
As you can see I have done componentcount the numbers show that the three labels should be there also I individually tried sysout title.isDisplayable() title.isVisible()
title.isShowing() all of these are true but still the title, welcome, ctandd is not displayed when I return to my admin JFrame

Comment: typing error Sorry it is Interface and not abstract class.

Comment: No one to help on this AAAH